# How to make application browser compatible

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser

I am building an application which is working fine in IE8 and Mozilla Firefox,but not in IE7. I like firebug and I like to debug my application using that,but currently I am struggling with browser compatibility thing. I found that application developed is working in IE8,FF11 but not in IE7(mainly layout is highlighly impacted). I am using jquery for browser related functionality and the jquery thing seems to be working..what shall I do to make layout working fine in IE7?
Framework used is spring3,hibernate..
I have huge set of CSS I dont think pasting that here will be any helpful.I have used postion relative and used top,left position some things..padding and margin are used but not that much..is that the cause? what is the possible suggestion? why IE7 and IE8 render things in different way? Shall I load different set of CSS for IE7,using spring? is it good solution?if yes then how to do that in spring?
Shall i discard using firebug and rely on IE8 debugger because our client mainly use IE7

Comment: hack the client's computer and install firefox :P jk

Comment: You should really try formatting your question into human readable form. I gave up after the first sentence. ( Few line breaks here and there wouldn't hurt )

Comment: Internet explorer compatibility, welcome to Hell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser compatibility is a very lengthy topic and it covers more than one area to perform correctly.

If IE 7 or IE browsers are your only problem, then `CSS Conditional comments` is the **PERFECT** solution for you.

Create a separate stylesheet, with all the neccessary fixes for IE7 browser. Then call the script is such a way, only IE 7 will render it.

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="ie7fix.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Now, the above stylesheet is only apply, in case if the browser is IE 7. So, all your fixes will be applied, thus the layout will be fixed. :)

---

*<sup>To read more about conditional comments, read [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).</sup>*

Answer (score 0):

Your App's UI can be optimized for IE7 too.
You have to add some css specific for IE7 for those properties (like position etc.) which are causing problem in IE7.
Before your css property add a dot. Like.

```
h1{
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #d39933;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    .padding-bottom: 10px; //For IE7
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IE7 and IE8 have different CSS support, with different bugs and oddities. It's common practice to load the CSS conditionally in those browsers in order to address those deviations from the standardised way of interpreting CSS. You may load additional CSS using IE conditional comments:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie7.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Here's an article on conditional comments you just might be interested in reading: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no magical solution in your case, and you will have to suffer ;=) , but i can give you a couple of tips that will help.

1/ IE's builtin debugger was improved over differents version, so you should use the latest version of IE to debug, and use the "Browser mode" combo-box from the debugger window (F12) to set it on "Internet Explorer 7", it works really well, I never found a difference between this mode and the real IE 7, and you have the debugging capabilities of IE 9.

2/ There are a few bugs in IE7 that you will have to work around with specific CSS, or javascript in some case, but a difference in the layout is not always a bug. Layout problems in IE7 are often the result of problematic constraints which resolved differently by different browsers. Typical example: in absolute position, you specify left, right, and width, there are too much constraints and differents browsers won't deal with that exactly the same way.

3/ IE specific css

```
<!--[if IE 7]> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="/css/ie7.css" /> 
<![endif]-->
```